# Typescript type checking not working with my decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

Consider the following method in my `Map` class:

```
@XYLiteralDecorator
setCenter(xy: XY | XYLiteral): void {
    this.mapI.centerAt((<XY>xy).projectToPoint(3978));
}
```

This is the `@XYLiteralDecorator` decorator used above:

```
function XYLiteralDecorator(target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function(maybeXY: XY | XYLiteral): XY {
        return originalMethod.apply(this, [isXYLiteral(maybeXY) ? new XY(maybeXY[0], maybeXY[1]) : maybeXY]);
    };
    return descriptor;
}
```

You'll notice in the `setCenter` method I need to force `xy` to be of type `XY` since TS will complain `xy` can be either `XY` or `XYLiteral` otherwise. However my decorator will always ensure `xy` is of type `XY`.

Is it possible for TS to know `xy` can only be of type `XY` while at the same time allowing both `XY` or `XYLiteral` types to be passed as parameters (without forcing types like I'm doing above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an overload that contains the union type parameter and have the implementation have the actual parameter type:

```
setCenter(xy: XY | XYLiteral): void;
@XYLiteralDecorator
setCenter(xy: XY ): void {
    console.log(xy.getX());
}
```

This works as expected, you can call with either type and the implementation will know the actual type:

```
dds.setCenter(new XY(0,0));
dds.setCenter([1, 1]);
```

Full sample [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20XY%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20constructor(public%20_x%3A%20number%2C%20public%20_y%3Anumber)%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getX()%20%7B%20return%20this._x%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Atype%20XYLiteral%20%3D%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D%3B%0D%0Afunction%20isXYLiteral(xy%3A%20XY%20%7C%20XYLiteral)%3A%20xy%20is%20XYLiteral%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20dd%20%3D%20xy%20as%20XYLiteral%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%20dd.length%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20XYLiteralDecorator(target%3A%20Object%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string%2C%20descriptor%3A%20TypedPropertyDescriptor%3Cany%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20originalMethod%20%3D%20descriptor.value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20descriptor.value%20%3D%20function(maybeXY%3A%20XY%20%7C%20XYLiteral)%3A%20XY%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20originalMethod.apply(this%2C%20%5BisXYLiteral(maybeXY)%20%3F%20new%20XY(maybeXY%5B0%5D%2C%20maybeXY%5B1%5D)%20%3A%20maybeXY%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20descriptor%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20DD%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setCenter(xy%3A%20XY%20%7C%20XYLiteral)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40XYLiteralDecorator%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setCenter(xy%3A%20XY%20)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(xy.getX())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20dds%20%3D%20new%20DD()%3B%0D%0Adds.setCenter(new%20XY(0%2C0))%3B%0D%0Adds.setCenter(%5B1%2C%201%5D)%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Not sure you can overload like that since the interpreter would not know which method to pick given a XY argument.

Comment: Tested works, the only overload that appears is VS code intelisense is the one with the union type. It is counter intuitive :)

Comment: Oh ok I didn't see you actually implement only the XY type.